# Sessions not persisting across the code in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce, shopping-cart, laravel-7

I'm buiding an e-commerce website in Laravel 7 and I'm trying to do a shopping cart with sessions. I know there are many packages I can use for, and I tried to use some of them with no success, but that's not the problem I wanna talk about here.

At first, the code is very simple, I have two methods: **index** and **add**.

**index method**

```
public function index(){
    
    var_dump(session()->get('testCart'));
    die();

    return view("cart.index");
}
```

**add method**

```
 public function add(){

    $cart = [
        "id" => 1,
        "product" => "PS4",
        "qty" => 1,
        "totalPrice" => 300
    ];

    session(["testCart" => array($cart)]);

    return view('cart.index');

 }
```

That's the code, as I said before, very simple for this test. I also have a route to add products to my cart.

**routes/web.php**

```
// CART
Route::get('/carrito', 'CartController@index')->name("cart.index");
Route::get('/carrito/add', 'CartController@add')->name("cart.add");
```

The first step I do, of course, is go to */carrito/add* and then to the route */carrito*. But when I go to this last route, the code doesn't find my cart session and it gives me a NULL.

*NOTE: I have noticed that sometimes the index method finds my session and shows its value. But most of the time it doesn't.*

I hope my English was clear enough to describe my problem properly, if you need more code or information, make me know it.

Thanks in advance,
Ciro.

Comment: Hi @elGoye, think your question is quite clear. May i ask what do you use as your session driver?

Comment: @HalilÇakar Hey!, I'm glad to know that. Yeah! my session driver is file.

Comment: Nice, I don't know if there is a problem with file session driver but we've always used database driver for sessions cause we also started having some problems. Maybe just maybe try database driver =)

Comment: @HalilÇakar Thank you very much! I tried with the database driver and it works great for now!.

Comment: Yea no problem i actually really don't know if there is a problem with file driver but atleast database driver works for sure. We are using it on our production :D

Comment: I think there is. But yeah, I didn't even thought about the database one!